# Javascript quotes conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, quotes, quote

I need to send a function as string as parameter of another function like this sample:

```
<a href="#" onclick="retryAjaxLoading('$('form#ajaxForm').trigger('submit');'); return false;">Por Favor, Tente Novamente!</a>
```

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

You could use escaped double-quotes:

```
<a href="#" onclick="retryAjaxLoading(\"$('form#ajaxForm').trigger('submit');\"); return false;">Por Favor, Tente Novamente!</a>
```

But the definitely best solution is to write all your scripts inside the `script` tag. You're using jQuery, so it'll be easy to write something like

```
$("#container a").click(function() 
{
    //Place your code here.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#" onclick="retryAjaxLoading('$(\'form#ajaxForm\').trigger(\'submit\');'); return false;">Por Favor, Tente Novamente!</a>
```

A better way would be to separate the code from the HTML and add either a class or id to the a tag

```
<a id="WhateverUniqueID" href="#">Por Favor, Tente Novamente!</a>

$("#WhateverUniqueID").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    retryAjaxLoading($("form#ajaxForm").trigger("submit"));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this which will escape the double quotes in the `onclick` attribute.

```
<a href="#" onclick="retryAjaxLoading(\"$('form#ajaxForm').trigger('submit');\"); return false;">Por Favor, Tente Novamente!</a>
```